# Publishing beta version of an app as Production version

Tags: android, google-play

Until now we have been releasing beta version of our Android app as beta version (publishing it on **open track**). Now we have a task to release our app as production-ready version (publishing it on **production track**) but elements of beta will still be there (like icons and UI elements).

When we tried to publish our iOS app it was rejected because of icons containing beta in them which were interpreted as sign of beta version of the app.

Can the Android app be rejected for the same reason? How does reviewing Production-ready Android apps happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Play Store currently will not reject an App for icons saying Beta. In fact, some apps (eg Chrome) have a completely separate "Beta" app which is published in production: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.beta

It even has "Beta" in the app title.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and bringing clarity to our lives :) Good to hear it. I thought that it is only possible to invite some users to become a beta tester who's going to use beta version while the rest will continue using production-ready version.